# windows explorer file search not working

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-search

When I search for files in windows explorer, it does not find any files ("No items match your search.") event though I can see the files in the directory.

For example, searching for "*.h" finds nothing.

Used to work just fine.

Windows-7 Pro 64-bit

Comment: That's an interesting one. Try to search with disabled indexing service. Than try the same with re-enabled indexing service. See if it makes any difference. Also triple-check all the search options. You might have set a search directory or something like this.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the search index yet?